# Node and MySQL - Solving a "Too Many Connections" issue

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, node-orm2

I have an application running on **Node.js** and **Express** using a **MySQL** database. The driver I'm using is **[node-orm2](https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2)**. Our users keep reporting a "**Too Many Connections**" error, and I've diagnosed the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Basically what is happening is, every time a new user visits the site, the driver **creates a new thread/process** for them. I can do a `SHOW PROCESSLIST` query on the db and it will show up there with a `Time` of `0`.

If the user makes another action that requires the database, that **same thread is re-used**, and the `Time` goes back to `0`. However, if they do not, the **thread stays alive** (with a `Command` of `Sleep`), and the `Time` racks up. The db has a max connection limit of `250`, and a timeout of `7200`.

So basically, if more than 250 people use the site within a period of 2 hours, we see the "Too Many Connections" error.

I tried using a **connection pool**, but that made the problem worse. Each time a new user used the database, it created 10 threads, and when the 7200 second timeout was reached, **the thread respawned**.

**What options do I have here?**

My current method is running a scheduled job every half hour to close threads that have been open for too long, but is there a better way?

I'm using the following settings:

```
db.settings.set("properties.association_key", "{name}Id");
db.settings.set("instance.autoFetch", true);
db.settings.set("instance.returnAllErrors", true);
db.settings.set("instance.cache", false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connection pools might be worth revisiting. One selling point of connection pools is that you can configure them to reclaim idle or stuck connections after a certain amount of time. So even if your application leaks connections the database is protected.

I know that doesn't address your root problem of the threads, but it's probably prudent to reclaim connections in any case.